# use of multiplication law of probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

As picking of 2 cards from a deck of cards without replacing the first , are two dependent events,then why in case of calculating the probability of picking 4 cards from a deck of 52 without replacing and all are aces , we multiply the probabilities.
$$\frac{^4C_1}{^{52}C_1}\cdot\frac{^3C_1}{^{51}C_1}\cdot\frac{^2C_1}{^{50}C_1}\cdot\frac{^1C_1}{^{49}C_1}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that is a case of multiplying conditional probabilities.

Let $A_k$ be the event that the $k$-th card drawn from the deck is an ace.

$$\mathsf P(A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4) ~{ = \mathsf P(A_1)\cdot\mathsf P(A_2\mid A_1)\cdot\mathsf P(A_3\mid A_1,A_2)\cdot\mathsf P(A_4\mid A_1,A_2,A_3) \\ = \dfrac{4}{52}\cdot\dfrac{3}{51}\cdot\dfrac{2}{50}\cdot\dfrac{1}{49} }$$

$\mathsf P(A_2\mid A_1)= {^3C_1}/{^{51}C_1}$ is the probability for selecting one of the aces remaining when selecting one from the deck where one ace has been removed.   And so forth.

Comment: Multiplication rule can be applied on independent events only?

Comment: If you mean that the joint probability of events equals the product of their marginal probabilities *only when* they are independent, then yes, that is so.